# Unable to get the list value returned by the json query from the ansible facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to get the size_available value for the /home filesystem from the ansible facts.

I am using the following code after setting gather_facts: True

```
{{ansible_facts['mounts']|json_query('[?mount==`/home`].size_available')}}
```

This way I get something like this [34545646] with msg: from the debug module.
I need to compare this value to a static one and continue or not the playbook but when I try:

```
{{ansible_facts['mounts']|json_query('[?mount==`/home`].size_available')[0]}}
```

I get:

```
"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '['. String: > {{ansible_facts['mounts']|json_query('[?mount==`/home`].size_available')[0]}}
```

Even if the type_debug shows me the result should be indeed a list that should be accessible by the [0] extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parenthesize the initial expression before attempting to index the result, like this:

```
{{
  (
    ansible_facts['mounts'] |
    json_query('[?mount==`/home`].size_available')
  )[0]
}}
```

E.g., if I run this playbook on my system:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            (
              ansible_facts['mounts'] |
              json_query('[?mount==`/home`].size_available')
            )[0]
          }}
```

I get this output for the debug task:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "402658955264"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Get the `size_available` value for a `mount` point from the ansible facts."***

A: Declare the dictionary below, for example in *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/mount_vars.yml 
mount_size_available: "{{ ansible_mounts|
                          items2dict(key_name='mount',
                                     value_name='size_available') }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
  mount_size_available:
    /: 8480206848
    /boot/efi: 30278656
    /export: 12902629376
```

Then, you can easily reference an available size at a mount point, for example

```yaml
  mount_size_available['/export']: '12902629376'
```

---

Example of a project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── mount_vars.yml
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

2 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/mount_vars.yml 
mount_size_available: "{{ ansible_mounts|
                          items2dict(key_name='mount',
                                     value_name='size_available') }}"

size_1G: "{{ 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }}"
size_10G: "{{ 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }}"
size_100G: "{{ 100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }}"
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  
    - setup:
        gather_subset: mounts
    - debug:
        var: mount_size_available

    - debug:
        var: mount_size_available['/export']

    - debug:
        msg: "Free space at /export is greater than 10G."
      when: mount_size_available['/export'] > size_10G|int

    - debug:
        msg: "Free space at /export is less than 100G."
      when: mount_size_available['/export'] < size_100G|int
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  mount_size_available:
    /: 8479465472
    /boot/efi: 30278656
    /export: 12901998592

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  mount_size_available['/export']: '12901998592'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Free space at /export is greater than 10G.

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Free space at /export is less than 100G.

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```